# onerror event to html tag object

Tags: javascript, html, onerror

In the below code, all the onerror event are working fine except the one mentioned in the "Object" tag. There is no file with the name "helloworld.swf" but the onerror event is not triggered. Can anyone please explain this.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
window.onerror = function (msg, url, line) {
   alert("Message : " + msg );
   alert("url : " + url );
   alert("Line number : " + line );
}
//-->
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p>Click the following to see the result:</p>
<form>
<input type="button" value="Click Me" onclick="myFunc1();" /><br/>
<input type="text" dir="rtl">
</form>
<object width="400" height="400" data="helloworld.swf" onerror="alert('helloworld.swf not found')"><br/>
</object>
<img src="myimage.gif" onerror="alert('image not found')"/><br/>
</body>
</html>
```

P.S : Refer to link "http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onerror.asp" which clearly says onerror event is supported by "object" HTML tag.

Comment: w3c and mdn dont have onerror attribute for the object tag. Ref: http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/object and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/object. Please refer MDN or other standardized sites. They have good and standard documentation.

Comment: http://www.w3fools.com/ please, use other documentation

Answer (score 1):

`<object>` has a `load` event but doesn't consistently have an `error` event. The latter appears to depend on the type of object loaded.

In Chrome the following only fires `load`, in Edge, IE and FX it fires `error`:

```js
var logDiv = document.getElementById('log');
function logEvt(e) {
  logDiv.appendChild(document.createTextNode("\n\t" + e.type + ": " + JSON.stringify(e)));
}

var obj = document.getElementById('obj');
obj.addEventListener('error', logEvt);
obj.addEventListener('load', logEvt);
```

```css
#log { border:1px solid black; }
```

```html
<object id="obj" width="100" height="100" data="not-there" type="image/png">Content shown on error.</object>
<pre id="log">Log:</pre>
```

That could be a bug in Chrome only.

The [documentation you have referenced](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onerror.asp) uses the term *object* to refer to the instance of the element being subscribed to, not specifically the `<object>` tag. The examples refer to the `<img>` tag, which does fire an `error` event.

Neither [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/object) nor [W3](https://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/object) seem to specify any events for the `<object>` tag.